# how to get content inside div in django?

Tags: html, django

i have the code below, i want to get the code inside the div and store it in the database.
usually in the  with attribut name i have no problem.
for this html

```html
<input type="text" name="post_title"/>
```

in my views.py i have

```py
        if request.POST:
            title = request.POST['post_title']
```

but now i have

```html
                  <div id="editor">
                    <p>Hello World!</p>
                    <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
                    <p><br /></p>
                  </div>
```

i want to get the html code inside the div with id editor.

Comment: Please post your html and view for our reference. Also, are you familiar with Django forms?

Comment: You have to use a form and input fields. You can't submit arbitrary divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you jQuery to get html. I think this will work

```
$('#your-form').submit(function(){
    $('#your-input').val($('#editor').html())
});
```